# Some question about classes in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, plugins

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and and I am trying to implement a new plugin. In order to learn, I am viewing inside and I am studying some popular plugins.

What I choosed is [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and in [a its file](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate.rb) there is something like this:

```
module WillPaginate
  class << self
    ...
  end
end

if defined? Rails
  WillPaginate.enable_activerecord if defined? ActiveRecord
  WillPaginate.enable_actionpack if defined? ActionController
end
```

I would like to know

1. **Why the `if defined? Rails` statement is outside the `module` statement? When will be run istructions inside that?**
2. **What means and how can\should I use `class << self`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `module WillPaginate` defines Ruby name scope and groups these methods so they can be later included with one call into some class. The `if defined? Rails` is outside the module because the code inside that `if` might include the **whole** module into some ActiveRecord class. And the `if` is executed exactly at the time when `will_paginate.rb` file is loaded.
2. All methods in that block are class methods. So later it is possible to make calls like `YourModelClass.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The `if defined? Rails` block is evaluated at load time, ie during `require 'will_paginate'`.  That allows will_paginate to be used with or without Rails.

The `class << self` section is a way to define a group of methods on the WillPaginate module without having to define them all as `def self.method_name`.  Either way works (except for a few edge cases I can't remember now), so it's mostly just a style choice.